# Cookie is not being set - PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

** Update - Problem Solved ** My code was correct, except I needed to specify the directory. the file setting the cookie was located in a subdomain, therefore skipping the root directory. I changed the code to set the cookie as so:

```
setcookie('Remember','remembercheck',time()+3600,'/','.mydomain.com');
```

and it now sets correctly.

** End Update **

when i attempt to login WITHOUT checking the remember me button, the cookie is not being set and I am not being logged in. If I log in WITH the remember me button checked, it logs in fine. Any ideas? I am stumped!

PHP:

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

session_name('login');

session_start();

// ---------- LOGIN ---------- 

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{   
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['remembercheck'] = (int)$_POST['remembercheck'];

        $storedsaltquery = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT rand FROM membertable WHERE usr = '".$_POST['username']."'"));
        $storedsalt = $storedsaltquery['rand'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr, FROM membertable WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='{$_POST['password']}'"));

        if($row['id'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['remembercheck'] = $_POST['remembercheck'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie("Remember","remembercheck");

        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    echo header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit;
}
```

HTML:

```
<?php

require 'includes/connect.php';
require 'includes/functions.php';

session_name('crmLogin');
// Starting the session

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['Remember']) && !$_SESSION['remembercheck'])

{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the Remember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the remembercheck checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>

    <form name="login" action="includes/logincheck.php" method="post">

                Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br>
                <input name="remembercheck" id="remembercheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember Me&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/><br><br><br>
   </form>
```

Comment: Which browser(s)? Have you watched the Set-Cookie header with developer tools or Fiddler? Is your code running in the top-level page or in a frame?

Answer (score 0):

use `setcookie` function we should set a expire time

please look at  Description :

> bool **setcookie** ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )

*expire*

> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number
> of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set
> this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you
> want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will
> set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the
> cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser
> closes).

So you should do like this:

```
setcookie("pfRemember","rememberPFcheck",time() + 3600)
```

much more look at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)